# How to get the first part of a email address in iOS?

Tags: nsstring, ios7.1, nsregularexpression

I want to get the first part of an email address in iOS. That means
 If I have a `NSString` like this

`NSString *strEmail=@"username@email.com";`
I want to extract the "username" part from this string and assign to a new string. How can I write the regular expression for this?

Please help me
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"]` This will split the string by '@' symbols, you can then take the first element.

Comment: how can I give the @ symbol inside the @" " Is it as [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\@"]?